# Meteor 1.2 Pass @Index to Child Template

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

Just started using Meteor so I might be missing something basic. In Meteor 1.2 they have the `{{@index}}` directive.

In a template if I have:

```
...
{{#each items}}
    {{@index}}
    {{> childTemplate}} 
{{/each}}
...
<template name="childTemplate">
{{@index}}
</template>
```

The `@index` in the main template will work, but the one in the childTemplate won't. The work around I've done to use it is to call the childTemplate passing in `@index`:

```
{{> childTemplate @index=@index}}
```

Is this the correct way to do it? Or is there something more meteory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's fine

There's a similar question I answered here :-

[How to get the @index of nested #each in meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32728619/how-to-get-the-index-of-nested-each-in-meteor)

But in this case passing it in is good.

Meteor has `"../var"` to get to the parent context, but that is the template context, not the each block, so I don't think there is a more meteory way

Comment: Thanks, I was just going to map it to a different variable, or even index without the `@`, but calling it `@index` seems flexible. I'm still a bit unsure why the child template doesn't get access to this `@index`, probably should have asked in the question.